# Issue with setting NSString from another class - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a search bar that once the search button is clicked, will call another class that will set a local `NSString` for that class.  The issue is when setting it in a function, I can call it there but if I call it from outside of that function when I move the user to that `ViewController`, it outputs weird things such as:

```
<UIKBCacheToken: 0x10c385df0>
```

Here what I am doing:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSString *searchType = searchBar.text;
    // SET TEXT
    search_results* myScript = [[search_results alloc] init];

    [myScript startProcess:searchType];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToSearchResults" sender:self ];
}
```

The above is my calling method within another class.

Here is my `startProcess`:

```
- (void)startProcess:(NSString*)searchPeram {
    NSString *check = searchPeram;
    useToSearch = check;
    NSLog(@"%@",useToSearch);
}
```

This works great and that variable is set and outputs correctly with lets say `test`.

Now once the `performSegueWithIdentifier` is called.  I try outputting the variable in the `ViewdidLoad`.  But it would output weird things such as the above first statement.  The `NSString` is being called as followed in the `.m` file:

```
@implementation search_results
NSString *useToSearch = @"";

- (void)viewDidLoad
```

Suggestions and thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code you are creating a new ViewController `myScript` ...

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSString *searchType = searchBar.text;
    // SET TEXT
    search_results* myScript = [[search_results alloc] init];

    [myScript startProcess:searchType];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToSearchResults" sender:self ];
}
```

but that isn't the one that is actually being displayed, you need to implement `prepareForSegue`...

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"moveToSearchResults"]) {

        search_results * myScript = (search_results *) segue.destinationViewController;

        [myScript startProcess:searchBar.text];
     }
}
```

and you `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` changed to this

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"moveToSearchResults" sender:self ];
}
```

I would also suggest that the searchString in your `search_results` view controller is made into a property that you can set, rather than using startProcess